# PayPal NVP/SOAP checkout express still supported?

Tags: soap, paypal, nvp

I'm providing support to a website that uses Express Checkout. The website sends Name Value Pairs, to this endpoint: api-3t.paypal.com/nvp

I'm confused about whether this is already deprecated or not, and whether it will continue working in the future.

This page about the NVP/SOAP integration on Express Checkout says that this method is deprecated since January of 2017: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/

Yet this page about the NVP/SOAP API doesn't say anything about it being deprecated: https://developer.paypal.com/reference/

The website uses these methods: doDirectPayment, SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

Is the NVP/SOAP integration for express checkout the same thing, or different from the NVP/SOAP API?

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#how-long-will-you-support-nvpsoap-apis says "At the moment, there's no time line for removing NVP/SOAP APIs. We will continue supporting and improving NVP/SOAP APIs when requests are made.

Eventually, the REST API will replace the NVP/SOAP APIs. We'll let you know in advance about any changes and provide resources to help you migrate to the REST API."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They aren't deprecated.  They're just trying to get people over to the REST APIs, but there are still way too many people using NVP/SOAP for them to kill it.  Also, the NVP/SOAP API still has more features available than REST, so they won't be able to fully kill it until REST gets completely caught up, which could take another couple of years at least.  Even at that time, if they do decide to kill NVP/SOAP they'll give you a year or two of advance notice to get your stuff moved onto REST.

If you don't want to worry about it at all, and if REST has everything you need then you may just want to go ahead and use that.

Comment: Thank you Andrew!

Comment: Have a look at the supported countries with the rest api though! https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-api-payment-country-currency-support/?mark=supported%20countries%20for%20rest%20api

Comment: ...also all african countries are excluded! Why and why?

Comment: ALL code from classic API with samples: https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php use git clone as download zip leaves samples out(!?)

Comment: If you are you using PHP I'd recommend taking a look at our library instead:  https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library.  You can clone it or install via Composer.  It has a much more simplified design and more templates / samples.